# Ignore everything but specific directories using .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I need to ignore every under `/src` directory but not `/src/BankBundle`. For that in my `.gitignore` file I do this:

```
/vendor/*
/app/cache/*
/app/logs/*
/web/uploads/*
/web/bundles/*
/app/config/parameters*
.DS_Store
/src/BankBundle/Resources/public/example.html
composer.lock

/src/*
!/src/BankBundle
```

This isn't working because any changes I made outside `/src/BankBundle` less say in `/src/AnBundle` SmartGit recognizes as a change and then show me for COMMIT, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure SmartGit will respect and knows how to read your `.gitignore` file? What happens when you use `git status` at the command line?

Comment: @Cupcake well I think the problem is `SmartGit` since in my Netbeans project those folder are ommited ;'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried these three ignore paths in a local test repo:

```
/src/BankBundle/Resources/public/example.html
/src/*
!/src/BankBundle
```

In `/src/BankBundle`, there is a file `hello.txt`. When I run `git add .` and `git status`, the `example.html` file is ignored, but `hello.txt` is added.

So it looks like your `.gitignore` file is set up correctly.